# facebooks graph api

Tags: facebook

if facebook uses the https system why doesnt the system be slow as there is so much data to encrypt even as each person,album is a separate object on the social graph.please i want t know this so even if the question might seem supid to some please nswer it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They probably use hardware encryption. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSL_acceleration

Answer (score 1):

It is obviously slower than it would be with HTTP, but Facebook has a lot of servers, so there's reasonably good concurrency and latency is minimized.

Answer (score 0):

1. Alot of servers. ( more than 30k)
2. Caching techniques.
3. Javascript from another servers, html from another and images definitely from another more and more servers to help the real facebook.com